# Backward Euler's Method

Tags: numerical-methods

This question was asked in CSIR. please help me to find out correct choice

---

Let $y(t)$ satisfy the differential equation $$y'=\lambda y;y(0)=1$$.
 Then the backward Euler method for $n\geq 1$ and $h>0$ $$\frac{y_n-y_{n-1}}{h}=\lambda y_n;\quad y(0)=1$$ yields

1. a first order approximation to $e^{\lambda nh}$
2. a polynomial approximation to $e^{\lambda nh}$
3. a rational function approximation to $e^{\lambda nh}$
4. a Chebyshev polynomial approximation to $e^{\lambda nh}$

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Check correct answer before bounty expired, otherwise it will be lost for everybody (because there is only 1 vote for each answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is (1).

Let us prove it:

An the solution is to apply Taylor series.
Let $y_n$ be the approximation point or the center of series, because it is occurs twice per numerical scheme.

$y(x)=y(c)+\frac{1}{1!}(x-c)y'(c)+...+\frac{1}{n!}(x-c)^n y^{(n)}(x_0)+...$

Let $c:=x_{n};\quad x:=x_{n-1};\quad y_n:=y(x_n);\quad y_{n-1}:=y(x_{n-1});\quad h:=x_n-x_{n-1}$

$y_{n-1} = y_{n} - h y'(x_{n})+\frac{h^2}{2}y''(x_{n})-\frac{h^3}{6}y'''(x_{n})+...$

$\frac{y_{n} - y_{n-1}}{h} = y'(x_{n}) - \frac{h}{2}y''(x_{n})+\frac{h^2}{6}y'''(x_{n})-...$

We may show that residual depends on step $h$ linearly:
$0=\frac{y_{n} - y_{n-1}}{h}-y_n=
\underbrace{(y'(x_{n})-\lambda y_n)}_{=0} - \frac{h}{2}y''(x_{n})+\frac{h^2}{6}y'''(x_{n})-...=O(h)
$

So it is first order approximation.

You can find more info about finite difference method on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method).

Comment: You can find more info about finite difference method on [wiki][1].
Tikhonov and Samarskii wrote "Numerical methods", it may be the official source for themethod.

Answer (score 0):

Since the explicit solution of that recursion is
$$
y_n=\Bigl(1-\frac{λnh}{n}\Bigr)^{-n}
$$
you get for $nh=t$ fixed a well-known approximation of the exponential $e^{λt}$. Using the logarithm series you can find the approximation order.

---

2. and 3. are ambiguous since they do not specify the variable of the function, i.e., what is considered fixed in those expressions.